# Discord.py voiceClient.is_connected() not working

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a music bot in discord.py and i'm trying to stop the bot from joining a channel when it has already joined one. But when I try this it throws an error. Please help me as I have already searched on google and on stack overflow but that has yielded nothing.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")


@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="testing")
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if not voice.is_connected():
        await channel.connect()


@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        ctx.send("There is no channel to leave.")


@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
    else:
        ctx.send("No audio is playing.")

client.run("I can't show you this.")
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCG0a.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full traceback error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that you are trying to use a voice client, that you haven't "created" yet. You create them by connecting to a voice channel, and if you were to use ?play or ?leave or ?pause without the bot beeing connected to a voice channel, it throws an `AttributeError` what you could do is:

```py
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="testing")
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None: #test if voice is None
        if not voice.is_connected():
            await channel.connect()
    else:
        await channel.connect() #if it's None, just connect because it can't be connected. Also this "creates" a VoiceClient which you can use.
```

Now you should test in every command that is fetching a voice client `if not voice is None`, and if it is, do something different in each command, for `?leave` for example, if `voice` is `None`, you aren't in a channel so you don't have to leave anymore.

So your full code would be:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")


@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="testing")
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None: #test if voice is None
        if not voice.is_connected():
            await channel.connect()
    else:
        await channel.connect()


@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None:
        if voice.is_connected():
            await voice.disconnect()
        else:
            await ctx.send("There is no channel to leave.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("There is no channel to leave.")


@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice is None:
        if voice.is_playing():
            voice.pause()
        else:
            await ctx.send("No audio is playing.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("I am currently not in a channel.")
client.run(Token)
```

---

**References:**

- [discord.VoiceClient](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#voiceclient)

Comment: When try your solution and run the commands nothing happens the bot doesn't join the voice channel at all. Sorry to ask again.

Comment: Hmm that's really strange, because it works for me! I just updated the answer to contain the full code, can you check if there is something different @Yaxiyaq

Comment: How am I able to use the VoiceClient that channel.connect() creates?
I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Just use `VoiceClient = channel.connect()` @ColinDave